# SSH "Could not open input file: bin/magento"

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm working through the Hello World tutorial and it's time for me to enter the "$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade" command for the reason mentioned in the tutorial but I get the error: "Could not open input file: bin/magento" and when I try to navigate to the Magento dir in bin it doesn't exist.

[image]

[image]

Help please? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the first error seems to say, that the bash can't find php.

**edit:** like versedi stated in the comments, the first error is raised because you copied the $ sign into the command.

also you just have to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

If you run `cd bin` first, it it `./magento`. The `.` points to the current directory. Otherwise, it searches for the `magento` command in your executable paths, which you can see by executing `echo $PATH`.

Eventually, you have to give it execute permissions first. You can do this by running `chmod +x bin/magento`

Comment: It can't find php because he pasted the '$' mark when copying the commands.

Comment: Aaaah ok right. Did Not See that

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I have my magento site as , `htdocs\magento2`

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy

php C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento indexer:reindex
```

Use full directory path instead of short path. 
It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on windows and solved it by this command instead:

```
php bin\\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I doubled the `\` to `\\`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on my local setup when I was missing file named 'magento' under **bin** directory of Magento root.

After copying the file to this location issue resolved.